# what is the difference between while(i>0) and while(i)

Tags: c

The following loop appears in some of our sample C codes:

```
while (i > 0)
    printf("We are still in the loop and counting down %d ...\n", i--);
```

Since the while-loop terminates when i becomes 0, we may remove the “> 0”,
 test as:

```
while (i)
    printf("We are still in the loop and counting down %d ...\n", i--);
```

So what is the possible consequences resulted from such a change?
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz0Rp.png)

Comment: What if `i` is negative?

Comment: `while(i)` means `while(i != 0)` which is not exactly the same as `while( i > 0)`.

Comment: Post relevant code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the data type of `i`:

`while(i)` means: "Loop as long as `i` is not zero"; `while(i>0)` means: "Loop as long as `i` is neither zero nor negative".

If `i` is a variable of an `unsigned` data type it cannot be negative so `while(i)` and `while(i>0)` have the same meaning.

If `i` however is a `signed` or floating-point variable this is not the case.

In your example however `i` obviously cannot become negative...

Comment: that makes sense! Thanks!